# Android OCR (Optical Character Recognization)

Tags: java, android, ocr

I want to develop one application which read text from the image. Which library i should have to use?

Comment: Getting started http://www.coderanch.com/t/506270/Streams/java/read-text-image-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[google ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/)

This library might be helpful for you. you can use this for optical character recognition. But to use this you have to learn how to work with android ndk. 
Here is a sample code using ocr 
[sample code](http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/ is a dead link.